# How do I check if a string is a callable name in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My project has an input field(returns a string), So I want to check if that input is a callable function name in python.

Here is an example of how my code look like, but it doesn't work:

```
n = 'print'

if callable(n):
    print('This is a callable function')
else:
    print("NA")
```

Comment: look the function in globals/locals dict first

Comment: In what context do you have to be exact? Is this in global or local scope, or even class and closure?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: No. This smells of [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do you want the user to be able to run "some" specific functions? If so, use a dict, map strings to allowed functions. If not, what is the goal behind this?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I want the user to be able to run some functions.

Comment: _I want the user to be able to run some functions._ That's a bad idea, you might as well just `eval()` the input directly. There are much better ways of doing this. The suggestion by @ParitoshSingh to use a dict is a straightforward solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) that returns a dictionary representing the current global symbol table, where you can search for particular function, also take a loot at [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

```
func = getattr(globals()['__builtins__'], 'print')
print(callable(func))
```

---

How @user2357112supportsMonica suggested that it would be more stable to use `builtins` module instead:

```
import builtins
func = getattr(builtins, 'print')
print(callable(func))
```

Comment: The name could also be defined in a non-local scope, in which case it's not sufficient to look in `globals()` and `locals()`.

Comment: `globals()['__builtins__']` is a needlessly convoluted way to access `__builtins__`, which is itself the wrong way (as in, it will actually fail in common cases) to access the `builtins` module. Just `import builtins` and use that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica good point. I've updated the answer. But not sure why it will fail in common case?

Comment: @funnydman: In imported modules, `__builtins__` will typically be `builtins.__dict__` rather than `builtins`.

Answer (score 1):

an example that works also for other scopes:

```
try:
    res = eval(f'callable({func})')
except NameError, SyntaxError:
    res = False

if res: ...
```

Note that it's dangerous to use `eval` on untrusted input

Answer (score 0):

maybe this answer is not that suffisticated, but some practical result:
when defining a function like:

```
def iamcallable(input): 
    return(print(input)) 
n = iamcallable('some INPUT') 

if callable(iamcallable): 
    print('This is a callable function') 
else: 
    print("NA")
```

Output:

```
some INPUT
This is a callable function
```

Hint:

```
'>>>callable?'
```

gave:

```
Signature: callable(obj, /)
Docstring:
Return whether the object is callable (i.e., some kind of function).

Note that classes are callable, as are instances of classes with a
__call__() method.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```